# Is my JSON an array or an object?

Tags: php, android, json

```
1[[23[]]
```

I understand that '[' denotes a JOSNArray and '{' denotes a JSONObject. However as my result starts with [ is the entire data piece now an array even if { comes before the actual string?

And if parsing in android, should I be parsing for array or object?

My PHP script:

Answer (score 1):

It's an array contsining single object. The string delimits name of the first item of the first object.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Zbynek Vyskovsky its an array with single object so to get the data you can use

```
         JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(<your json object>);
         JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0);
         String date = jsonObject.getString("Date");
         String temp = jsonObject.getString("Temp");
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Will I need a for loop also?

Comment: If your jsonArray contains more than one object you will need a for loop to iterate through it. Same concept as in a normal array.

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is an array which contains only one Json object.I will show actually how it works with JSon Array and JsonObject.

For example I have a JSON Array  :

```
[{
        "name": "abc",
        "description": "ABC server",
        "state": "online"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "description": "XYZ client",
        "state": "online"
    },
    {
        "name": "mnp",
        "description": "MNP server",
        "state": "online"
    }]
```

So The above array actually contains 3 Json objects like `[{Obj1},{Obj2},{Obj3}]`.

When we try to get any of the value for a key then first we need to store the JSon Array and then after we need to get the exact Json object by passing index e.g: `jsonObject obj = JsonArray.get(0)`.

Soon after you pass the key to the Json object in `get()` method, you will get your key. e.g: `String s = obj.get("state")`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine this is format first .
paste your response in this site http://json.parser.online.fr/

there you will see

1)red square brackets -represent an array.

2)blue curly brackets represents an object.

in short you have an array containing single object.